# Determine whether $ [ (p \implies q) \land ( q \implies r)] \implies r $ logically implies the proposition $ (p \implies r) \implies r$ is True

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Determine whether the proposition $ [ (p \implies   q) \land ( q \implies  r)] \implies r $ logically implies the proposition $ (p \implies r) \implies r.  $

Note that  $ [ (p \implies   q) \land ( q \implies  r)] \implies (p \implies r) $ is a  tautology, but this statement has some subtle difference.

Is there some laws/rules that may be of help here?

(It is indeed False, if we draw a Truth Table to verify)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $(p \to r) \to r$ is False.

This means $r$ False and $p$ False.

Now consider the premise: $[(p \to q) ∧ (q \to r)] \to r$.

With the above values we have  $[(\bot \to q) ∧ (q \to \bot)] \to \bot$, that means: $[\top ∧ (q \to \bot)] \to \bot$.

If we choose True for $q$ we have that the premise will be: $[\top ∧ (\top \to \bot)] \to \bot$ that evaluates to True.

Conclusion: we have found that the truth assignment of False, True, False to $p,q,r$ respectively satisfies the premise and falsifies the conclusion, i.e. the conclusion is **not** logically implied by the premis.

Answer (score 0):

The implication holds when $p \rightarrow r$ also implies $(p \rightarrow q) \land (q \rightarrow r)$. That is, $p \rightarrow r$ must imply $p \rightarrow q$. But as you know it is generally not true because we don't even know what $q$ will be. you can replace any statements only when they are equivalent.